# #include <avifile.h> requires #include <stdlib.h> before to make build succeed

Tags: c++, avi

I need to use the avifile library (https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libavifile-0.7-dev) in C++.

I have the following `main.cpp` file as a minimal reproducible example :

```cpp
#include <avifile.h>

int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to build the `main.cpp` file inside a Docker container (for reproducible builds), using this `Dockerfile` to install only needed dependencies :

```
FROM    debian:stretch

RUN     apt update \
 &&     apt install -y \
            g++ \
            libavifile-0.7-dev
```

When I build inside the container :

```
g++ -o main.o main.cpp `avifile-config --libs` `avifile-config --cflags`
```

, which resolves to the following command :

```
g++ -o main.o main.cpp -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -laviplay -I/usr/include/avifile-0.7
```

The build gives many errors, for example :

```
In file included from /usr/include/avifile-0.7/avm_stl.h:8:0,
                 from /usr/include/avifile-0.7/avifile.h:4,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/avifile-0.7/avm_stl.h: In member function 'void avm::vector<Type>::erase(avm::vector<Type>::iterator)':
/usr/include/avifile-0.7/avm_stl.h:333:12: error: 'm_size' was not declared in this scope
     assert(m_size > 0);
            ^
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
/usr/include/avifile-0.7/avifile.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/avifile-0.7/avifile.h:96:13: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
     virtual size_t GetHeader(void* pheader = 0, size_t size = 0) const =0;
             ^~~~~~
/usr/include/avifile-0.7/avifile.h:104:13: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
     virtual size_t GetAudioFormat(void* format = 0, size_t size = 0) const =0;
             ^~~~~~
```

The import `#include <avifile.h>` is responsible of the errors. The errors are related to avifile headers, so I can't modify them. It looks like the build cannot find some basic stuff, like `m_size` and `size_t`. If I add `#include <stdlib.h>` before :

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <avifile.h>

int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

Then, it builds fine.

Why do I need to include `stdlib.h` along with `avifile.h` here? I'm not very familiar with C++, but I understand that `m_size`, `size_t`, ... (all required by avifile) is defined in `stdlib.h` though.

Comment: I guess `avifile.h` is not self contained and is missing some includes. Treating `size_t` as a built-in type seems to be a common mistake.

Comment: Whoever produced the file `avifile.h` (which is a 3rd party thing, not a standard header) did not check the dependencies properly.  If they had, they would have necessary `#include`s within it.    Report this as a bug to whoever supplied that file.

Comment: `libavifile` is very old, the last release was 14 years ago, when C++03 was actual.

Comment: Thanks for you comments. I'm working on a very old application, that's why....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as you have already deduced, is that there is code in the `avifile.h` that uses variables or class members declared with the [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) type, which is *not* an in-built data type but a 'user'-defined `typedef` declared in one of the standard system headers. The `stdlib.h` header (though it's better to use `<cstdlib>` in C++ code) will automatically include that header, if required, as will other system headers, like `<iostream>` and `<cstddef>`.

Generally, third-party headers, like `avifile.h` should themselves check for the necessary header dependencies, and explicitly `#include` them if required. However, it seems that, in your case, that header does not do so.

So, for now, you should ensure that you always `#include` one of the system headers before your `#include <avifile.h>` line. *In your situation, I would also contact the providers of that library to let them know about the problem, which (IMHO) should be considered an **error**.*

Incidentally, the `m_size` you mention is *not* a standard type, but is more likely to be a member variable of one of the classes that is declared as a `size_t` variable.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do I need to include stdlib.h along with avifile.h here?

You answered yourself a bit later:

> I understand that m_size, size_t, ... (all required by avifile) is defined in stdlib.h though.

Specifically, `size_t` is defined by `stdlib.h`, `m_size` is just a poor variable in your header defined as type `size_t`, and since the compiler couldn't figure out what that type is, it doesn't consider it defined at all for the purposes of further error checking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, as the comments under the question suggests, whoever produced `avifile.h` have missed to include `stdlib.h` in that file? Is that an ordinary thing in C++ or more like a mistake in libavifile?

Comment: I don't know how common it is, I've never encountered it before, but then again I mostly code in C#. Whether it's a mistake or not is also up for debate, it's possible there's a readme file coming with your library where they explain the need to include `stdlib.h`. It's definitely not nice, but life itself is also seldom nice lol

Comment: @norbjd As I said in my answer, I would consider it an error - very poor coding, IMHO. It's really trivial to add the extra `#include <cstddef>` to their header, and *that* file will have 'guards' to prevent multiple inclusion/definitions/etc.

Comment: I mean, considering that the library in question uses Windows binaries through wine to play video files, and according to the online documentation it only works in 32-bit (and was last updated in 2006), I think your standards are a tad high. If you want quality you use ffmpeg!

Comment: @norbjd Yes, that's a bug, and should be reported to the author.

Comment: Actually, this is an old application that I'd like to build on GNU/Linux platform, so at the moment, my only goal is to make it able to compile first :).